# Venn Diagram Puzzle : How many people use tablets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

> In a market survey on the use of notebooks and tablets, it was found that, of the total respondents,
>
> - $52$ use notebooks,
> - $31$ use tablets and
> - $29$ use only notebooks.
>
> With the data above, we conclude that, of the total respondents, ______ use only tablets.

To solve this problem I made $52$ that is the total of people that uses notebook minus $29$ people that uses only notebooks.And then I got $26$ that I subtract from $31$ people that use tablets getting the number of $5$ people that only use tablets. Is my logic correct?

Answer (score 1):

$52-29$ is $23$ not $26$, and the answer should be $31-23=\fbox{8}$ not $31-26=5$

Otherwise, it's correct.